# Java JNLP download loop

Tags: java, windows-10, jnlp

We have a JNLP file that on some computers gets stuck in a download loop.
When the download it started the user is presented with an "Open" or "save" option and no matter which they choose it seems to start a new download and present them with the same 2 options.

It seems to only happen on Windows 10, though not always.
Java version is 8 update 161
The same thing appears to happen in Edge, Firefox, and Chrome.

Supposedly it was resolved one time by going into java configurations, and deleting temporary internet files, however I have not been able to replicate this issue.

Has anyone experienced this sort of thing?  I tried searching around a bit online but nothing seems to match.  This is the first time I've made an account to ask a question, please let me know if you think there is any other relevant data I should provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.  It seems users had associated the .jnlp file to "Open with" a browser, as a result any time they tried to open a .jnlp file they had downloaded the browser treated the file like a new download.  We simply needed to re-associate the "open with" to point at the javaws.exe.

The piece that helped clarify this was realizing that the files were in the downloads folder, so they were downloading.  They must have just chosen a poor association at some point.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. As JNLP will disappear in future java generations, take a look into javapackager and such.